# Address of converted object

Tags: c++

How would I pass this by it's address without additional variables?

```
(VkSurfaceKHR)surface.get()
```

I can't do:

```
&(VkSurfaceKHR)surface.get() /*or*/ &((VkSurfaceKHR)surface.get())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do: `&(VkSurfaceKHR)surface.get()` /*or*/ `&((VkSurfaceKHR)surface.get())`"?

Comment: Visual Studio: "expression must be an lvalue or a function designator"

Comment: So is `get` returning a temporary? If so you will have to use a variable. Why wouldn't you want to use a variable out of interest?

Comment: It seems unnecessary and ugly to have an extra variable for that

Comment: I mean, temporaries are destroyed when they're out of scope as a fundamental part of the language. It has some exceptions a `const&` can bind to a temporary. You could look to retrieve a non temporary handle, though presumably `VkSurfaceKHR` is itself just a pointer anyway. Though if this is the design Vulkan uses, I wouldn't bother fighting it personally. If it's runtime performance you're worried about then don't be, this being a problem would show up during profiling and there's likely much bigger fish to fry. (C++ is an ugly language :))

Comment: VkSurfaceKHR objects are already pointers (or pointer equivalent opaque objects); they are safe and cheap to copy; since they are only references to the underlying surface. Are you sure you actually want to take the address of the `VkSurfaceKHR`?

Comment: @Mankarse Well, I just want to pass my vulkan.hpp `vk::UniqueSurfaceKHR surface` to the GLFW function `glfwCreateWindowSurface`

Comment: @SM64: In that case, just do `&surface.get()`. `UniqueSurfaceKHR::get()` returns a reference, so you can take its address. Your problem only occurs when you (unnecessarily) cast the reference to a `VkSurfaceKHR` non-reference type.

Comment: Or just follow the [example used in the sample code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/7feffc1b9d62031c45daabb93470c3ee8b096326/samples/05_InitSwapchain/05_InitSwapchain.cpp#L44)

Comment: @Mankarse `&surface.get()` is not possible. Visual Studio: "C++ argument of type `vk::SurfaceKHR*` is incompatible with parameter of type `VkSurfaceKHR`"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, that `(VkSurfaceKHR) surface.get()` will create a new temporary `VkSurfaceKHR` object (aka rvalue) which only lives for the duration of the expression.

As the compiler rightfully tells you, you can't take addresses of rvalues, but need a lvalue, i.e a named variable.

In case `surface.get()` returns a reference type of a polymorphic type and the actual underlying object happens to be `VkSurfaceKHR`, you can use `dynamic_cast<VkSurfaceKHR&>` to get a properly typed reference and then take the address of that.

Comment: Huh, turns out I can't do dynamic_cast on the surface